# JUnit with Java 8 Clock

Tags: java, junit, java-8, java-time

Imagine we have the following class that I would like to test:

```
class Times {

    Clock cl = Clock.systemDefaultZone();

    public int changeTime() {
        LocalDate ld = LocalDate.now(cl);
        if(ld.getMonth().equals(Month.OCTOBER))
            return 1;
        if(ld.getMonth().equals(Month.NOVEMBER))
            return 2;
        return 0;
    }
}
```

How can I force the date to be in November and assert that the method returns 2?

I am using JUnit and Mockito.

Comment: You can use the respective LocalDate factory method, for example: LocalDate.of(int year, int month, int dayOfMonth);

Answer (score 5):

Assuming there is a setter for the `Clock` object in `Times` class, you can do something like this:

```
Times times = new Times();
Clock fixedClockInNovember = Clock.fixed(Instant.parse("2015-11-01T00:00:00.00Z"), ZoneId.of("UTC"));
times.setClock(fixedClockInNovember);
assertEquals(2, times.changeTime());
```

In this code, a fixed clock is created. This simulates a constant time for the given instant, that is in November.

As such, any call to `LocalDate.now(clock)` will always return the *same* date in November.

Comment: so without this setter we're not able to change clock inside Time class?

Comment: Well you can with a little bit of reflection magic but can't you add a setter?

Comment: @MichałWolnicki Probably better than a setter (which allows changing the clock to an existing and potentially share instance of Times - and that's messy) would be to pass the Clock to the constructor.